# Why darmstadtium has more than one eletronic configuration? (Aufbau Principle)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Darmstadtium aparently has two possible eletronic configuration

via Aufbau Principle:

1s² 2s² 2p⁶ 3s² 3p⁶ 4s² 3d¹⁰ 4p⁶ 5s² 4d¹⁰ 5p⁶ 6s² 4f¹⁴ 5d¹⁰ 6p⁶ 7s¹ 5f¹⁴ 6d⁹

but for some reason at times I see it distributed as:

[Rn] 7s² 5f¹⁴  6d⁸

I know that the only way to properly tell what is Darmstadtium eletronic configutarion is via experimental measurements, but why does it have two completely different distributions?

Comment: For the second you give, you aren’t leaving two unpaired orbitals …

Comment: Where did you get the first $7s^15f^{14}6d^9$ configuration from ?  A reference would be useful as  I'm not seeing that anywhere and my own application of the basic Aufbau rule give the second result.

Comment: [1st distribution](https://ptable.com/?lang=pt#El%C3%A9trons) I got from ptables, and the [second](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/element/Darmstadtium) I got from pubchem

Comment: @hcp If you want to reply to a comment you need to prefix the username of the person you are replying to.  This ensures they get a notification, otherwise they won't generally know you have replied.  Authors of posts get notified automatically on comments.